# Why does my S3 bucket not work as subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a publicly viewable bucket which works fine when addressed like `http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucketname]/directory/file.jpg` but when using the following schema `http://[bucketname].s3.amazonaws.com/directory/file.jpg` returns:

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Key>directory/file.jpg</Key>
  <RequestId>...</RequestId>
  <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Did I unintentionally change something in my s3 configuration? I can't be 100% sure but I thought a) this was working until recently and b) this should work regardless of configuration setup.

If it's at all germane, my bucketname is all caps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because DNS names are case-insensitive, only lowercase bucket names are addressable by the virtual hosting method.

via [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingLimitations) page. "Virtual hosting" in this case just means `<bucketname>.s3.aws.com` style addressing versus path-style addressing like `s3.aws.com/<bucketname>/`.